# If I use a baseController class do I need to specify USING in the children?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

If my base class has something like:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using MFA.Storage.Helpers;
using MFA.Storage.Models;
using MFA.WebUx.Areas.Administration.ViewModels.Notes;
using MFA.WebUx.Areas.Administration.Services.Notes;
using MFA.WebUx.Areas.Administration.ActionFilters
using System;
```

Then in my child classes that inherit from the base controller do I still need to add all the using directives? Is that a good or bad practice?

Comment: This is totally nit-picking, but your using directives are out of order. :) (System first, then everything else alphabetically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`using` directives do not "inherit" (their scope is confined to the file in which they are declared), so you will need to add them to the descendant class as well, unless both classes reside in the same file.

From a best practice perspective, it's probably better to keep each class in it's own file, and add `using` directives to each class file as needed.

Comment: just a correction, there are two uses of using keyword, when used as a statement, it defines scope of object, when used as a directive,you can import or alias the namespaces.

Comment: @Adeel, Robert specifically referred to the using *directive*

Comment: Ahh, glorious. My apologies, @Adeel.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't NEED those `using` directives if you don't use them.  The only one you need for sure is the namespace of the base controller.

However, it's not really considered "bad practice" to include them ... many of Visual Studio's default files have several `using`s that aren't used by default.  As long as the extra `using`s don't create conflicts, then just keep them there.  It's much easier to leave them there than it is to add them back later.

As a side note, there are some GREAT plugins that help you organize the `using` directives.  I use Resharper, which "grays-out" any useless `using` directives, indicating that they can be removed.  And when a `using` directive is missing, it finds it and lets me add it easily.
Visual Studio 2010 also lets you add missing `using` directives, so it's not a big deal to remove extra `using`s.